# Cakephp Auth: bypassing login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a CakePHP application which is part/sub another application that is developed in different technology ( ColdFusion ). Both apps have their own login functionality and they are required. Login functionality in CakePHP is by AUTH and ACL . Now the requirement is that when a user logged in parent app which is developed in ColdFusion user should directly go to protected pages/dashboard without logging in. I want a way to bypass the login functionality provided by Auth.

Thank you,

kiran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want a way to bypass the login functionality provided by Auth.

You probably don't, you probably want to be able to log the user in automatically, [which Auth supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650605/cakephp-2-0-automatic-login-after-account-activation).

You need to have some way for your PHP code to call ColdFusion to authenticate a user based on some shared secret (e.g. the login cookie for the ColdFusion part of the application) and then automatically log the user if they are authenticated.

Comment: Sorry! wrong choice of words. I mean the same. Thanks for the link.