# Cakephp after register auto log in

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to auto log in after I register? Im using this code, after I Save the data

```
$this->UserAuth->login($user);
$this->redirect('/');
```

but this is not working

Comment: Try this syntax : $this->Auth->login($user['User']); Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650605/cakephp-2-0-automatic-login-after-account-activation

Comment: I dont have AuthComponent.php. I change mine UserAuthComponent.php @Senthil

Comment: Try this code : $cuser = $this->User->findById($id);
$myuser = $cuser['User'];
$this->UserAuth->login($myuser );